# Is there escaping closure/callback in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, callback, closures

Is it possible to use Escaping callBack/closure in Objective-C?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Objective-C have an equivalent to Swift's @escaping annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52879202/does-objective-c-have-an-equivalent-to-swifts-escaping-annotation)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Objective C How to return outer function from inside async inner function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52580164/objective-c-how-to-return-outer-function-from-inside-async-inner-function)

Comment: It is not duplicate @Willeke, please read again the question and if you know the answer, please write your answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing a method taking a block to use as callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180552/implementing-a-method-taking-a-block-to-use-as-callback/7180612)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, blocks passed into a function can, by default, escape the function it is passed into, unless the parameter is marked `NS_NOESCAPE`.

Comment: Hi @newacct, can you please provide an example